# How to export XML Powershell system.object[] arrays to CSV file

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following XML received from a web service in a PowerShell variable $res

```
<GRID>
  <DATA>
    <R>
      <D>2645</D>
      <D>HJIT.HRE@RGW.COM</D>
      <D>2019-09-27 10:17:36.0</D>
      <D>114041</D>
      <D>Awaiting Planning</D>
      <D>Work Planned</D>
    </R>
    <R>
      <D>2649</D>
      <D>HJIT.HRE@RGW.COM</D>
      <D>2019-09-27 10:33:24.0</D>
      <D>114043</D>
      <D>Awaiting Release</D>
      <D>Awaiting Planning</D>
    </R>
    <R>
      <D>2652</D>
      <D>HJIT.HRE@RGW.COM</D>
      <D>2019-09-27 10:36:53.0</D>
      <D>114041</D>
      <D>Awaiting Planning</D>
      <D>Work Planned</D>
    </R>
  </DATA>
</GRID>
```

I want to export the R nodes as rows and D node values as columns into a CSV file in PowerShell. I did the following:

```
$res.GRID.DATA.R | Export-Csv .\GRID1.csv
```

The result is the correct number of rows, but columns do not appear, instead I get the object type like so:

```
"D"
"System.Object[]"
"System.Object[]"
"System.Object[]"
```

What is the quickest way to get the columns converted to comma separated values ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$res.GRID.DATA.R` outputs `System.Xml.XmlElement` instances, which `Export-Csv` doesn't (meaningfully) support.

You have to transform these elements into `[pscustomobject]` instances first.

The challenge is that there are no distinct property names, given that that the child elements of the input elements are all named `D`.

The following solution therefore constructs property names `C1`, `C2`, ... to allow the transformation into a `[pscustomobject]`.

```
$x.GRID.DATA.R | ForEach-Object { 
  $oht = [ordered] @{}
  $i = 1
  foreach ($val in $_.GetEnumerator().InnerText) {
    $oht[('C' + $i++)] = $val
  }
  [pscustomobject] $oht
} | Export-Csv .\GRID1.csv
```

With your sample XML file, the above yields:

```
"C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6"
"2645","HJIT.HRE@RGW.COM","2019-09-27 10:17:36.0","114041","Awaiting Planning","Work Planned"
"2649","HJIT.HRE@RGW.COM","2019-09-27 10:33:24.0","114043","Awaiting Release","Awaiting Planning"
"2652","HJIT.HRE@RGW.COM","2019-09-27 10:36:53.0","114041","Awaiting Planning","Work Planned"
```